# How to Focus last cell of visible cell of collection view?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I want to focus and change the frame of last cell of visible cell of collectionView.

I want collection view behaviour like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/42lgoe45fvv0kxw/Focuslayout.mov?dl=0).

I found the [library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SFFocusViewLayout) that change the first cell of collection view but I want to change the frame of last cell. This library using flow layout.

```
override func prepareLayout() {

cache.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

let standardHeight = UltravisualLayoutConstants.Cell.standardHeight
let featuredHeight = UltravisualLayoutConstants.Cell.featuredHeight

var frame = CGRectZero
var y: CGFloat = 0

for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
    // 1
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)

    // 2
    attributes.zIndex = item
    var height = standardHeight

    // 3
    if indexPath.item == featuredItemIndex
    {
            // 4
            let yOffset = standardHeight * nextItemPercentageOffset
            y = collectionView!.contentOffset.y - yOffset
            height = featuredHeight
    } else if indexPath.item == (featuredItemIndex + 1) && indexPath.item != numberOfItems {
            // 5
            let maxY = y + standardHeight
            height = standardHeight + max((featuredHeight - standardHeight) * nextItemPercentageOffset, 0)
            y = maxY - height
    }

    // 6
    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    //print("Item : \(item) : \(frame)");
    attributes.frame = frame
    cache.append(attributes)
    y = CGRectGetMaxY(frame)
}

}
```

[library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SFFocusViewLayout) uses above function to change the frame of all elements.

Can any one tell me that how can I achieve [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/42lgoe45fvv0kxw/Focuslayout.mov?dl=0).

Comment: https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell

Comment: he has used the same technique you are using the only difference is by tapping the cell..

Comment: @magid Thanks. I will try. Hope It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [visible cells of a UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells?language=objc) to get the array of visible cells and focus on the lastObject of the array